# Filter on distinct queryset pulls values omitted by 'distinct on' query - PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, filter, distinct

I have a large inventory of vehicles that I retrieve distinctly by their model number. Users can filter the vehicles by condition (New or Used). However in the backend, something strange happens. The distinct queryset's count is 683, and there are only two possible values for the condition, new and used. When filtering used vehicles though, I get 186, and when filtering new vehicles I get 521, 707 in total. I thought "Why is the number of new, and used together equal more than the original count". After further debugging, I found that even after doing a 'distinct on model_no', the new filter is pulling vehicles with a model number that should have been omitted in the distinct on query. Is the new filter somehow messing up the 'distinct on'

View

```
def search_listings(request):
    # Start searching

    all_listings = Inventory.objects.all().distinct('model_no')



    # This is what I did to find out there were extra model numbers coming in 
    master_test_list = []
    master_model_no = []
    new_list = []

    new_listings = all_listings.filter(condition='N')
    used_listings = all_listings.filter(condition='U')

    for item in all_listings:
        if item.id not in master_test_list:
            master_test_list.append(item.id)
            master_model_no.append(item.model_no)

    for item in new_listings:
        if item.id not in master_test_list:
            new_list.append(item)

    for item in used_listings:
        if item.id not in master_test_list:
            new_list.append(item)

    for item in new_list:
        print('{} is in original model_no list = {}'.format(item.model_no, item.model_no in master_model_no))
        print('{} is in original id list = {}'.format(item.model_no, item.id in master_test_list))

    for param in request.GET:

        values = request.GET[param].split(',')

        # Splitting dash delimited values from fields such as make, sometimes brings more than what you were looking for
        # e.g. Land Pride brings up New Holland, because Holland has the world 'land' in it.
        count = 0
        for val in values:
            if '-' in val:
                values[count] = val.replace('-', ' ')
            count += 1

        if 'all' not in values:
            if param.lower() == 'years':
                all_listings = all_listings.filter(model_year__iregex=r'(' + '|'.join(values) + ')')
            elif param.lower() == 'condition':
                all_listings = all_listings.filter(condition__iregex=r'(' + '|'.join(values) + ')')
            elif param.lower() == 'location':
                all_listings = all_listings.filter(location__name__iregex=r'(' + '|'.join(values) + ')')
            elif param.lower() == 'type':
                all_listings = all_listings.filter(inv_type__name__iregex=r'(' + '|'.join(values) + ')')
            elif param.lower() == 'manufacturer':
                all_listings = all_listings.filter(make__name__iregex=r'(' + '|'.join(values) + ')')

    return all_listings
```

Inventory Model

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    INVENTORY_STATUS = (
        ('A', 'Active'),
        ('S', 'Sold'),
        ('I', 'Inactive')
    )

    INVENTORY_CONDITION = (
        ('N', 'New'),
        ('U', 'Used')
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, help_text='Parent stock item CB_PORD column')
    inv_stock_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, help_text='CB_ORD column')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=INVENTORY_STATUS)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=INVENTORY_CONDITION, help_text='CB_TYP column from inv file')
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='inventory', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    inv_type = models.ForeignKey(Inventory_Type, related_name='inventory')
    inv_subtype = models.ForeignKey(Inventory_Subtype, related_name='inventory')
    make = models.ForeignKey(Inventory_Make, related_name='inventory')
    model_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, help_text='CB_MOD column from inv file')
    model_year = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='CB_MYR column from inv file')
    hours = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='CB_HRS column from inv file')
    serial_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, help_text='CB_MSN column from inv file')
    original_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, help_text='CB_OCS column from inv file')
    original_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, help_text='Calculated on original cost, can override')
    list_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,
                                     help_text='Calculated on original cost, can override')

    general_info = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)

    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    date_added_to_inv = models.DateField(blank=True, help_text='CB_DTA column')
    date_modified_in_inv = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='CB_DTM')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON` (and `DISTINCT` in general, in any other RDBMS) is applied after the `WHERE` predicate filters. This is by design. For what you want to do, you'll need a sub-select on SQL level, which applies the `DISTINCT ON` clause & you can filter its results at the outer select.

Comment: Ahhh I see, thanks pozs !